# segue.identifier not working in if block

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Can anyone explain to me why assigning segue.identifier to a variable evaluates to true in the if block but doing everything in the if block doesn't work? This is on Xcode Version 6.2 (6C121)

```
var id = segue.identifier // This works
if id == "tweetDetailsSegue" {
  var detailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TweetDetailsViewController
  var cell = sender as TweetCell
  detailsViewController.tweet = cell.tweet!
}

// This doesn't work
if segue.identifier == "tweetDetailsSegue" {
  var detailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TweetDetailsViewController
  var cell = sender as TweetCell
  detailsViewController.tweet = cell.tweet!
}
```

Comment: Works both ways for me. (Just tested it.) There must be something else going on... Could you post more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your literally doing the exact same thing in both versions. Do you get any error message?

If not, it very well might be a glitch in 6.2 (though I don't really see how this could be a glitch)